# How do I use the same form for Create, Details and Edit in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC CRUD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am studying ASP.NET Core MVC. I see ASP.NET MVC written, the controller usually has 2 overloads for each operation: `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`.

Like, for the `Create` action, there would be:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(ItemModel model)
{
    _dbContext.Add(model);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `Details` action is almost identical:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var model = _dbContext.Items.First(x => x.ID == id);
    return View(model);
}
```

The `Edit` action is identical in the controller, except it has a saving routine:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = _dbContext.Items.First(x => x.ID == id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(ItemModel model)
{
    _dbContext.Update(model);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I have not seen any tutorials that talk about using the same form to Display, Create, and Edit.

It seems like a simple exercise to edit the Create action so that it inserts a new item:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ItemModel(); // ID = 0, so this would be a new item
    return View(model);
}
```

To delete a model, I could set an Inactive bit on the class. Show the details, and have an Edit link that disables the read-only fields so they can be edited. That sounds like the way to go, but I don't see anyone doing it.

Is that not possible with MVC?

How would I write these `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` methods so that one form could be used instead of three?

Comment: Sorry, Your question is very unclear. `Display,delete,edit,Add` in the same form? Do you mean `delete,edit,Add` actions are not have their own pages. In Display page, each record has it's own `delete,edit,Add` button, User just do crud in this page instead of redirecting to related page?

Comment: @XinranShen one page can display the information (read-only), and it should be the same page for entering a new item or editing an existing item. The buttons on the form should be Cancel, Save, or Delete. Everything on one form.

Comment: If the page is read-only , How can you edit an existing item on it? I am not if you want to achieve that when i click edit button, Use Javascript to make this record can be edited, then i can update in this form.

Comment: In your scenario, I can use ajax to achieve ,But I am not sure if you accept it, I think it is more complex then use different pages to do crud.

Comment: @XinranShen - I was going to do like most other pages I see and add links to the Details page that have [Edit], [Return to List], and [Archive]. Clicking the [Edit] would disable all of the read-only fields. I'm just not sure how to do that or how to get the Controller to understand what I am doing.

Comment: Still can't get your point, What do you mean about `disable all of the read-only fields`? When clicking  edit button in a specified record, Then the page will redirect to details page about that record, Then you can edit this record in this detail page? could you please provide an example about what you said?